# How do I export a video using Digiflow code?

Tags: digiflow

I want to make a video for a presentation using Digiflow, converting a .dvi or .dfm file to a .avi. I would like the final image to have a set colour scheme and I would like the time displayed in the corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tools > Transform Intensity. Put the following in the space for Digiflow code.

```
    # Specify output image as a function of P
    hD := draw_start(P);
    draw_set_axes(hD,0,1,0,1);
    draw_font(hD,1,"Arial");
    draw_text(hD,0.15,0.03,make_string(Time.tNow,"f5.1")+" s","left");
    mask := draw_on_array(hD);
    mask := mask.image[:,:,0];
    P := where(mask,P,1);
```

This should put the time in the bottom left of the output image. To change the colour scheme use 'Options' for the output image and save as an .avi to convert.